# Actions link not supported by Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, native

I have a native application which uses *Facebook* through Graph API and I'm trying to add a custom action link to a wall post.

For example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?     
           message=Wpis&actions[{"name":"Look","link":"http://google.com"}]
```

The message is posted on the wall but the action link is not shown. (It also doen't work from Graph API Explorer).
I found in some posts that action link isn't supported by Graph API, only by old REST API. Can you confirm that info? Or maybe you could redirect me to the page where there i can find some info about lacking features in the Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a **=**

```
/me/feed?message=Wpis&actions=[{"name":"Look","link":"http://google.com"}]
                             ^
```